# Change image src on error with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image that sometimes returns a 404 error. To get the image to load, it usually works if the image src is slightly modified, for example adding "`?reload=true`" to the end of it. How do I do this using JavaScript?

```
<img src="example.com/image.png" onerror="reloadImage()">

<script>

function reloadImage() {

    // Set img src to "example.com/image.png?reload=true"

}

</script>
```

Comment: Pass `this` as an agument to `reloadImage`, and do `thisArg.src = "example.com/image.png?reload=true"` in the function.

Comment: Great! How do I also get the current src then add the "?reload=true" to it? The image source is not always "example.com/image.png", it might be "example.com/another_image.png" as well

Comment: You could be in danger of looping indefinitely - probably should have some break after a certain number of attempts - but better would be to find out why you are getting a 404 - is the image on  a server that you have some control over?

Comment: ??? `src` property of the [image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) is read/write string.

Comment: A Haworth the image comes from an API where the src is the API request. Sometimes it doesn't work right away, but when reloaded it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the element into the function, also clear the error event else it could infinite loop.

```
function reloadImage(img) {
  img.onerror = null

  let url = new URL(img.src)
  url.searchParams.set('reload', 'true')
  img.src = url.toString()
}
```

```
<img src="example.com/image.png" onerror="reloadImage(this)">
```

The ideal solution would be to track down why it's erroring in the first place and fix that.

Comment: Thanks! How can this be modified so that the new src from reloadImage() becomes the original src of the image with "?reload=true" tacked onto it?